# Time Series Analysis with Non-continuous Data

Tags: time-series

I'm puzzled on how to approach this problem.

Let me frame the problem like this:

I am looking to predict total sales for Q1 in year 2023.   I have only Q1 daily sales data for years 2022, 2021, and 2021.  No imputation for missing 3 quarters.

I can't put this data in a single series and use ARIMA because of the Gaps.

I have about 150 non zero data points (+ a about 20 more with weekends).

Guidance please on how to approach?